# JavaScript code works in Chrome console but not in MediaWiki's Common.js file

Tags: javascript, php, encoding, mediawiki, right-to-left

I installed MediaWiki 1.32.0 in Hebrew and there I ran the following code in Chrome console:

```
window.setTimeout(()=>{
    const [...elements] = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    elements.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.textContent == "hebrewTextContent") {
            element.textContent = "englishTextContent";
        }
    });
});
```

The code works fine in Chrome console - an Hebrew phrasing was changed to an English one;

Yet when I saved the file in MediaWiki's `Common.js` it didn't work:

- MediaWiki 1.32.0 doesn't have any cache
- clearing browser cache didn't help
- No relevant error pops in Chrome console
- [MediaWiki developers didn't recognize a specific problem](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:V2rg5hr6ex3ysa06)

**What may cause the problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try to run it via my browser it output me this error:

> Expected an identifier and instead saw '...'.
>
> Expected ',' and instead saw '...'.

Instead, use this code, it does exactly like what you want:

**Edit**

```
function toArray(arr) { return Array.isArray(arr) ? arr : Array.from(arr); }

window.setTimeout(function () {
    var document1 = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

    var document2 = toArray(document1);

    var elements = document2;

    elements.forEach(function (element) {
       if (element.textContent == "hebrewTextContent") {
           element.textContent = "englishTextContent";
       }
    });
});
```